# Center image in a link

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having an affiliate link and in it also an image.
It looks like this:

```
<a href="my/link"> <img src="my/image"> </a> <img src="my/image"/>
```

How can I center the whole thing?
I am using it inside a WordPress table through tablepress.

Comment: Please show an image of what you want. You likely need to wrap in a div

Answer (score 10):

Try this. Wrap the desired tags in a DIV, and apply `text-align:center` to that div.

```html
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
<a href="my/link"> <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50"> </a>
</div>
```

To center the image top/bottom and left/right at the same time, you can use either flexbox:

```css
.flexboxOnParentDiv{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxOnParentDiv">
<a href="#" style=""> <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50"> </a>
</div>
```

or grid:

```css
.gridOnParentDiv{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridOnParentDiv">
<a href="#" style=""> <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50"> </a>
</div>
```

**Note:**

For any of the examples, you can add the style properties

a. inside the `style=` tag on the div *(as in the first example)*,

or *(as in the latter two examples)* via:

b. A [`<style></style>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) within the document (body or head, whichever), or

c. in an external `filename.css` that you include via a [`<link rel="stylesheet" etc>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) tag in the head.

The first method (a), although used, is discouraged whenever possible. Method (c) is preferred wherever feasible.