# Hyperlinking Image

Tags: html, css

Given my current code, how would I go about hyperlinking an image, so that when the user clicks on the image, the browser opens a new tab, and displays the image?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}

.center-fit {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"> <img class="center-fit" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg/1363px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg'></div>
```

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: You can surround the `<img />` tag with an anchor tag (e.g. `<a href="..." target="_blank"><img ... /></a>`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center image in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030040/center-image-in-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way.

```
<a href='https://anywebsite.com/home'> 
    <img class="center-fit" src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg/1363px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg' />
</a>
```

You can wrap a anchor tag (`<a href='...'> </a>`) around anything and it will hyperlink it to anything.

You can also add `<a href='...' target='_blank' </a>` and it will

Comment: Yes, but then, the image is not centered:

CSS: 

.img {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .center-fit {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 90vh;
            margin: auto;
        }

HTML (original):

<div class="img"> <img class="center-fit" src='001.jpg'></div>

Please help - thanks! :)